# Optional Entries in the Tabular Environment

Tags: tables, macros, cards

I need to put together my bridge-related macros to produce complete bridge diagrams. A MWE and an example output is shown below:

```
%********************************************************************************
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in,paperheight=9in, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{array}
%********************************************************************************


%********************************************************************************
% Use MnSymbol suit symbols

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolCards}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.1] MnSymbolC5
   <6-7>  s*[1.1] MnSymbolC6
   <7-8>  s*[1.1] MnSymbolC7
   <8-9>  s*[1.1] MnSymbolC8
   <9-10> s*[1.1] MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> s*[1.1] MnSymbolC10
  <12->   s*[1.1] MnSymbolC12}{}

\newcommand{\mndiamond}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A2}}}
\newcommand{\mnheart}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A3}}}
\newcommand{\mnspade}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A4}}}
\newcommand{\mnclub}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A5}}}
%********************************************************************************


%********************************************************************************
% BRIDGE HAND
%********************************************************************************
\newcommand{\cardsep}{\hspace*{0.2em}}

% Defines a vertical bridge hand with seat name
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\hand}{sO{S,H,D,C}mm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \blackened_hand_horizontal:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
   {
    \blackened_hand:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_blackened_hand_seq
\clist_new:N \l_blackened_suit_clist

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_hand_horizontal:nnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_blackened_hand_seq { ; } { #3 }
  \hspace*{-1em}% remove the initial \quad
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { S }
   { \quad \mbox{\mnspade   \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 1 } } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { H }
   { \quad \mbox{\mnheart   \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 2 } } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { D }
   { \quad \mbox{\mndiamond \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 3 } } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { C }
   { \quad \mbox{\mnclub    \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 4 } } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_hand:nnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_blackened_hand_seq { ; } { #3 }
  \bool_gset_false:N \g_blackened_newline_bool
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \begin{tabbing}
  \tl_if_blank:nTF { #2 }
    { \bool_gset_false:N \g_blackened_newline_bool }
    { \bool_gset_true:N \g_blackened_newline_bool \textbf{#2} }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { S }
   { \blackened_newline: \mnspade   \= \cardsep \= \blackened_set_suit:n { 1 } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { H }
   { \blackened_newline: \mnheart   \= \cardsep \= \blackened_set_suit:n { 2 } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { D }
   { \blackened_newline: \mndiamond \= \cardsep \= \blackened_set_suit:n { 3 } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { C }
   { \blackened_newline: \mnclub    \= \cardsep \= \blackened_set_suit:n { 4 } }
  \end{tabbing}
  \end{minipage}
  \bool_gset_false:N \g_blackened_newline_bool
 }

\tl_const:Nn \c_blackened_ten_tl { 10 }
\tl_new:N \l_blackened_suit_tl
\seq_new:N \l_blackened_suit_seq
\bool_new:N \g_blackened_newline_bool

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_newline:
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \g_blackened_newline_bool
   { \\ }
   { \bool_gset_true:N \g_blackened_newline_bool }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_set_suit:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_blackened_suit_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_blackened_hand_seq { #1 } }
  \tl_if_blank:VTF \l_blackened_suit_tl
   { --- } % no card in the suit
   {
    \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l_blackened_suit_tl { 10 } { \c_blackened_ten_tl }
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l_blackened_suit_seq { } \l_blackened_suit_tl
    \seq_use:Nn \l_blackened_suit_seq { \cardsep }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%********************************************************************************

% Above macros are not directly related to this question,
% they are needed to to produce the diagrams


%********************************************************************************
% BRIDGE DIAGRAM
%********************************************************************************
\newlength{\myminipageparskip}
\newenvironment{bdminipage}
  {\setlength{\myminipageparskip}{1ex}% save the value
   \begin{minipage}[t]{3in}% open the minipage
   \setlength{\parskip}{\myminipageparskip}% restore the value
  }
  {\end{minipage}}

% bidding
\newenvironment{bidding}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{0.75in}\= \hspace*{0.75in}\= \hspace*{0.75in}\= \hspace*{0.75in} \kill
\textbf{South} \> \textbf{West} \> \textbf{North} \> \textbf{East}\\
}%
{\end{tabbing}\end{minipage}}%


\newcommand{\bdcomplete}[7]{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{ m{1in} m{1in} m{1in}}
\multicolumn{3}{m{3in}}{
\begin{bdminipage}
#1
\end{bdminipage}}\vspace{2ex}\\
   & #2 &\\
#3 & {\begin{tikzpicture} \draw (0,0) rectangle (1.3,1.3); \end{tikzpicture}} & #4\\
   & #5 &\\
\multicolumn{3}{m{3in}}{#6}\\
\multicolumn{3}{m{3in}}{
\begin{bdminipage}
#7
\end{bdminipage}}
\end{tabular}
}
%********************************************************************************




\begin{document}

The following deal was reported in the \emph{The Bridge World} magazine:

\begin{center}
\bdcomplete
{
East dealer,\\
North-South vulnerable
}
{\hand{North}{J432; 65; A53; QJ109}}%
{\hand{West}{K5; AK9732; 84; 876}}%
{\hand{East}{109876; J84; J; K532}}%
{\hand{South}{AQ; Q10; KQ109762; A4}}%
{
\begin{bidding}
2\mnheart \> Pass\> 3\mnheart \> Double \\
Pass\> 3\mnspade \> Pass \> 4\mndiamond \\
Pass\> 5\mndiamond\> Pass\> Pass\\
Pass
\end{bidding}
}
{
Contract: Five-clubs doubled by South.

Opening lead: Heart ace.

Closed Room Result: Five clubs doubled by the Brazilian South, down 1, +100 for Norway.
}
\end{center}
Some text following the diagram above.

\end{document}
```

[image]

When some of the options are blank, they still occupy a certain amount of vertical space, as in below:

```
\begin{document}

The following deal was reported in the \emph{The Bridge World} magazine:

\begin{center}
\bdcomplete
{}
{\hand{North}{J432; 65; A53; QJ109}}%
{\hand{West}{K5; AK9732; 84; 876}}%
{\hand{East}{109876; J84; J; K532}}%
{\hand{South}{AQ; Q10; KQ109762; A4}}%
{}{}
\end{center}
Some text following the diagram above.
```

[image]

How can I avoid such behavior.

(When I “feel” that the macros are mature, I plan to present them to bridge authors, players, etc. So any comment to make the **Bridge Diagrams** macros above more robust, more LaTeX way, more flexible in any way is appreciated. For example, there isn't enough vertical space between the bidding and the explanatory text below; I like to be able to control such details as much as possible.)

(I am aware that I can write separate macros for separate diagrams and needs.)

Comment: You may test if the argument is `null` and if so, do nothing. In `xparse` package you have the `\IfNoValueTF{}{}{}` that can help you on that.

Comment: @cacamailg: `\IfNoValueTF{}` operates only on optional argument, but `[]` would be regarded as non-null, i.e. it has a value then!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to use `\notblank{#1}{true}{false}` from `etoolbox` package to query whether an argument is empty or not and react correspondingly. However, it should not be used inside `\multicolumn` since those tabular cells would be typeset any way, regardless whether `#1` is empty or not.

Using

`\noalign{\gdef\temp@x{\notblank{#1}{\multicolumn{3}{m{3in}}{%...
}}{\@empty}}}\temp@x`

this will mask the query first (`\noalign`) and stores the execution to `\temp@x` which is then called afterwards. If `\temp@x` is empty, nothing is done.

Additional vertical space comes in when `#6` is empty --> a `\tabularnewline` is used anyway. I removed this with `\showonlyifnotempty{#6}`

The code for `#1` and `#7` with `bdminipage` is almost identical, so I defined `\showwithminipage{som}`, the starred version is used to suppress the `\tabularnewline` at the end of the `\multicolumn`. If the optional argument is not given, no `\vspace{...}` will be inserted.

Another possibility to cope with `{}` is to use optional arguments and `\NewDocumentCommand` instead, querying with `\IfValueT` but this does not prevent the `\noalign` approach.

```
%********************************************************************************
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in,paperheight=9in, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{array}
%********************************************************************************


%********************************************************************************
% Use MnSymbol suit symbols

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolCards}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.1] MnSymbolC5
   <6-7>  s*[1.1] MnSymbolC6
   <7-8>  s*[1.1] MnSymbolC7
   <8-9>  s*[1.1] MnSymbolC8
   <9-10> s*[1.1] MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> s*[1.1] MnSymbolC10
  <12->   s*[1.1] MnSymbolC12}{}

\newcommand{\mndiamond}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A2}}}
\newcommand{\mnheart}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A3}}}
\newcommand{\mnspade}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A4}}}
\newcommand{\mnclub}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A5}}}
%********************************************************************************


%********************************************************************************
% BRIDGE HAND
%********************************************************************************
\newcommand{\cardsep}{\hspace*{0.2em}}

% Defines a vertical bridge hand with seat name
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\hand}{sO{S,H,D,C}mm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \blackened_hand_horizontal:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
   {
    \blackened_hand:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_blackened_hand_seq
\clist_new:N \l_blackened_suit_clist

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_hand_horizontal:nnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_blackened_hand_seq { ; } { #3 }
  \hspace*{-1em}% remove the initial \quad
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { S }
   { \quad \mbox{\mnspade   \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 1 } } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { H }
   { \quad \mbox{\mnheart   \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 2 } } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { D }
   { \quad \mbox{\mndiamond \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 3 } } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { C }
   { \quad \mbox{\mnclub    \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 4 } } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_hand:nnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_blackened_hand_seq { ; } { #3 }
  \bool_gset_false:N \g_blackened_newline_bool
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \begin{tabbing}
  \tl_if_blank:nTF { #2 }
    { \bool_gset_false:N \g_blackened_newline_bool }
    { \bool_gset_true:N \g_blackened_newline_bool \textbf{#2} }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { S }
   { \blackened_newline: \mnspade   \= \cardsep \= \blackened_set_suit:n { 1 } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { H }
   { \blackened_newline: \mnheart   \= \cardsep \= \blackened_set_suit:n { 2 } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { D }
   { \blackened_newline: \mndiamond \= \cardsep \= \blackened_set_suit:n { 3 } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { C }
   { \blackened_newline: \mnclub    \= \cardsep \= \blackened_set_suit:n { 4 } }
  \end{tabbing}
  \end{minipage}
  \bool_gset_false:N \g_blackened_newline_bool
 }

\tl_const:Nn \c_blackened_ten_tl { 10 }
\tl_new:N \l_blackened_suit_tl
\seq_new:N \l_blackened_suit_seq
\bool_new:N \g_blackened_newline_bool

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_newline:
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \g_blackened_newline_bool
   { \\ }
   { \bool_gset_true:N \g_blackened_newline_bool }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_set_suit:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_blackened_suit_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_blackened_hand_seq { #1 } }
  \tl_if_blank:VTF \l_blackened_suit_tl
   { --- } % no card in the suit
   {
    \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l_blackened_suit_tl { 10 } { \c_blackened_ten_tl }
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l_blackened_suit_seq { } \l_blackened_suit_tl
    \seq_use:Nn \l_blackened_suit_seq { \cardsep }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%********************************************************************************

% Above macros are not directly related to this question,
% they are needed to to produce the diagrams


%********************************************************************************
% BRIDGE DIAGRAM
%********************************************************************************
\newlength{\myminipageparskip}
\newenvironment{bdminipage}
{\setlength{\myminipageparskip}{1ex}% save the value
  \begin{minipage}[t]{3in}% open the minipage
    \setlength{\parskip}{\myminipageparskip}% restore the value
  }
  {\end{minipage}}

% bidding
\newenvironment{bidding}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{0.75in}\= \hspace*{0.75in}\= \hspace*{0.75in}\= \hspace*{0.75in} \kill
\textbf{South} \> \textbf{West} \> \textbf{North} \> \textbf{East}\\
}%
{\end{tabbing}\end{minipage}}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\showonlyifnotempty}[1]{%
  \noalign{%
    \gdef\temp@x{\notblank{#1}{%
        \multicolumn{3}{m{3in}}{#1}
        \tabularnewline
      }{% false branch
        \@empty
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \temp@x
}

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\showwithminipage}{som}{%
  \noalign{%
    \gdef\temp@x{\notblank{#3}{%
        \multicolumn{3}{m{3in}}{%
          \begin{bdminipage}
            #3
          \end{bdminipage}
          \IfValueT{#2}{%
          \vspace{#2}%
          }
        }
        \IfBooleanF{#1}{%
        \tabularnewline % Only \tabularnewline if there is no star
        }%
      }{% false branch
        \@empty
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \temp@x
}




\NewDocumentCommand{\bdcomplete}{mmmmmmm}{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{ m{1in} m{1in} m{1in}}
  \showwithminipage[2ex]{#1}
  & #2 & \\
  #3 & {\begin{tikzpicture} \draw (0,0) rectangle (1.3,1.3); \end{tikzpicture}} & #4\\
  & #5 & \tabularnewline
  \showonlyifnotempty{#6}%
  \showwithminipage*{#7} 
 \end{tabular}%
}
\makeatother
%********************************************************************************





\begin{document}

The following deal was reported in the \emph{The Bridge World} magazine:
\hrule
\begin{center}
\bdcomplete
{Hello}
{\hand{North}{J432; 65; A53; QJ109}}%
{\hand{West}{K5; AK9732; 84; 876}}%
{\hand{East}{109876; J84; J; K532}}%
{\hand{South}{AQ; Q10; KQ109762; A4}}%
{More Text}{Even more text}
\end{center}
\hrule
\begin{center}
\bdcomplete
{}
{\hand{North}{J432; 65; A53; QJ109}}%
{\hand{West}{K5; AK9732; 84; 876}}%
{\hand{East}{109876; J84; J; K532}}%
{\hand{South}{AQ; Q10; KQ109762; A4}}%
{}{}
\end{center}
\hrule
Some text following the diagram above.

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit** Version with `long` arguments which allow par breaks:

```
%********************************************************************************
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in,paperheight=9in, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{array}
%********************************************************************************


%********************************************************************************
% Use MnSymbol suit symbols

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolCards}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.1] MnSymbolC5
   <6-7>  s*[1.1] MnSymbolC6
   <7-8>  s*[1.1] MnSymbolC7
   <8-9>  s*[1.1] MnSymbolC8
   <9-10> s*[1.1] MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> s*[1.1] MnSymbolC10
  <12->   s*[1.1] MnSymbolC12}{}

\newcommand{\mndiamond}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A2}}}
\newcommand{\mnheart}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A3}}}
\newcommand{\mnspade}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A4}}}
\newcommand{\mnclub}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A5}}}
%********************************************************************************


%********************************************************************************
% BRIDGE HAND
%********************************************************************************
\newcommand{\cardsep}{\hspace*{0.2em}}

% Defines a vertical bridge hand with seat name
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\hand}{sO{S,H,D,C}mm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \blackened_hand_horizontal:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
   {
    \blackened_hand:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_blackened_hand_seq
\clist_new:N \l_blackened_suit_clist

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_hand_horizontal:nnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_blackened_hand_seq { ; } { #3 }
  \hspace*{-1em}% remove the initial \quad
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { S }
   { \quad \mbox{\mnspade   \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 1 } } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { H }
   { \quad \mbox{\mnheart   \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 2 } } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { D }
   { \quad \mbox{\mndiamond \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 3 } } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { C }
   { \quad \mbox{\mnclub    \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 4 } } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_hand:nnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_blackened_hand_seq { ; } { #3 }
  \bool_gset_false:N \g_blackened_newline_bool
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \begin{tabbing}
  \tl_if_blank:nTF { #2 }
    { \bool_gset_false:N \g_blackened_newline_bool }
    { \bool_gset_true:N \g_blackened_newline_bool \textbf{#2} }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { S }
   { \blackened_newline: \mnspade   \= \cardsep \= \blackened_set_suit:n { 1 } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { H }
   { \blackened_newline: \mnheart   \= \cardsep \= \blackened_set_suit:n { 2 } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { D }
   { \blackened_newline: \mndiamond \= \cardsep \= \blackened_set_suit:n { 3 } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { C }
   { \blackened_newline: \mnclub    \= \cardsep \= \blackened_set_suit:n { 4 } }
  \end{tabbing}
  \end{minipage}
  \bool_gset_false:N \g_blackened_newline_bool
 }

\tl_const:Nn \c_blackened_ten_tl { 10 }
\tl_new:N \l_blackened_suit_tl
\seq_new:N \l_blackened_suit_seq
\bool_new:N \g_blackened_newline_bool

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_newline:
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \g_blackened_newline_bool
   { \\ }
   { \bool_gset_true:N \g_blackened_newline_bool }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_set_suit:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_blackened_suit_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_blackened_hand_seq { #1 } }
  \tl_if_blank:VTF \l_blackened_suit_tl
   { --- } % no card in the suit
   {
    \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l_blackened_suit_tl { 10 } { \c_blackened_ten_tl }
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l_blackened_suit_seq { } \l_blackened_suit_tl
    \seq_use:Nn \l_blackened_suit_seq { \cardsep }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%********************************************************************************

% Above macros are not directly related to this question,
% they are needed to to produce the diagrams


%********************************************************************************
% BRIDGE DIAGRAM
%********************************************************************************
\newlength{\myminipageparskip}
\newenvironment{bdminipage}
{\setlength{\myminipageparskip}{1ex}% save the value
  \begin{minipage}[t]{3in}% open the minipage
    \setlength{\parskip}{\myminipageparskip}% restore the value
  }
  {\end{minipage}}

% bidding
\newenvironment{bidding}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{0.75in}\= \hspace*{0.75in}\= \hspace*{0.75in}\= \hspace*{0.75in} \kill
\textbf{South} \> \textbf{West} \> \textbf{North} \> \textbf{East}\\
}%
{\end{tabbing}\end{minipage}}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\showonlyifnotempty}[1]{%
  \noalign{%
    \gdef\temp@x{\notblank{#1}{%
        \multicolumn{3}{m{3in}}{#1}
        \tabularnewline
      }{% false branch
        \@empty
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \temp@x
}

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\showwithminipage}{+s+o+m}{%
  \noalign{%
    \gdef\temp@x{\notblank{#3}{%
        \multicolumn{3}{m{3in}}{%
          \begin{bdminipage}
            #3
          \end{bdminipage}
          \IfValueT{#2}{%
          \vspace{#2}%
          }
        }
        \IfBooleanF{#1}{%
        \tabularnewline % Only \tabularnewline if there is no star
        }%
      }{% false branch
        \@empty
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \temp@x
}




\NewDocumentCommand{\bdcomplete}{+m+m+m+m+m+m+m}{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{ m{1in} m{1in} m{1in}}
  \showwithminipage[2ex]{#1}
  & #2 & \\
  #3 & {\begin{tikzpicture} \draw (0,0) rectangle (1.3,1.3); \end{tikzpicture}} & #4\\
  & #5 & \tabularnewline
  \showonlyifnotempty{#6}%
  \showwithminipage*{#7} 
 \end{tabular}%
}
\makeatother
%********************************************************************************






\begin{document}

The following deal was reported in the \emph{The Bridge World} magazine:

\begin{center}
\bdcomplete
{
East dealer,\\
North-South vulnerable
}
{\hand{North}{J432; 65; A53; QJ109}}%
{\hand{West}{K5; AK9732; 84; 876}}%
{\hand{East}{109876; J84; J; K532}}%
{\hand{South}{AQ; Q10; KQ109762; A4}}%
{
\begin{bidding}
2\mnheart \> Pass\> 3\mnheart \> Double \\
Pass\> 3\mnspade \> Pass \> 4\mndiamond \\
Pass\> 5\mndiamond\> Pass\> Pass\\
Pass
\end{bidding}
}
{
Contract: Five-clubs doubled by South.

Opening lead: Heart ace.

Closed Room Result: Five clubs doubled by the Brazilian South, down 1, +100 for Norway.
}
\end{center}
Some text following the diagram above.

\end{document}


\begin{document}
The following deal was reported in the \emph{The Bridge World} magazine:
\hrule
\begin{center}
\bdcomplete
{Hello}
{\hand{North}{J432; 65; A53; QJ109}}%
{\hand{West}{K5; AK9732; 84; 876}}%
{\hand{East}{109876; J84; J; K532}}%
{\hand{South}{AQ; Q10; KQ109762; A4}}%
{More Text}{Even more text}
\end{center}
\hrule
\begin{center}
\bdcomplete
{}
{\hand{North}{J432; 65; A53; QJ109}}%
{\hand{West}{K5; AK9732; 84; 876}}%
{\hand{East}{109876; J84; J; K532}}%
{\hand{South}{AQ; Q10; KQ109762; A4}}%
{}{}
\end{center}
\hrule
Some text following the diagram above.



\end{document}
```

[image]

**Request for optional arguments**

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\bdcompleteopt}{+m+m+m+m+m+O{2ex}+m+O{1ex}+m}{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{ m{1in} m{1in} m{1in}}
  \showwithminipage[2ex]{#1}
  & #2 & \\
  #3 & {\begin{tikzpicture} \draw (0,0) rectangle (1.3,1.3); \end{tikzpicture}} & #4\\
  & #5 & \tabularnewline[#6] % Optional space between #5 and #7
  \showonlyifnotempty{#7}%
  \showwithminipage*[#8]{#9} % Optional space between next to last and last line
 \end{tabular}%
}
```

Comment: Very good answer!

Comment: @cacamailg: Oh, thank you very much. Querying inside tables is a constant source of joy ;-)

Comment: @Christian Thanks for giving your time. Am I doing something wrong? When I substitute the portion between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document`, in my original MWE, I get an error.

Comment: @blackened: You mean the one with the longer example?  -- Ah yes, the `long` arguments ... Hm, I've to change something then

Comment: @blackened: See the update, please!

Comment: @Christian Same error.

Comment: @blackened: It works for me, otherwise I wouldn't have posted it

Comment: @Christian Now it works. Thank you. Is there a way to define custom vertical spaces between arguments #5 and #6, and #6 and #7 ?

Comment: @blackened: You could use optional arguments. As far as I consider this, the first, the sixth and seventh arguments are somehow optional already (You say `{}` for example). Please consider, that using two additional arguments transforms this to a macro with 9 parameters. This is cumbersome to remember which argument stands for which operation or content. I suggest a key-value interface rather then!

Comment: @blackened: I've added a fragment for a `\bdcomplete` routine with optional arguments. I don't recommend it however this way

Comment: I'll try to improve later on, but now I have to leave